# Discord.js Bot that Automatically Gives Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to find out how to give a person a role automatically once he joins a server on Discord.
The tutorial I watched didn't explain this very well.

Here's a snippet of I have so far:

```
const fs = require('node:fs')
const path = require('node:path')
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const { token } = require('./config.json')

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds], partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"] })
client.commands = new Collection()

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands')
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
```

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    guildMember.roles.add('ROLE ID')
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send(`<@${guildMember.user.id}> joined as <@ROLE ID>!`)
})
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what I should do?

Thanks!

I expected an automatic Discord bot that gives someone a role on joining, but I got nothing. Nothing seems to respond.

Comment: I think you need the MEMBER intent or something... IIRC they made it so that you need a specific intent to listen to guild member add and guild member remove events?

Comment: I think that's what I was going for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to cache the message first. And I also changed the intents.

Answer (score 0):

Discord has made it so that listening for member join events is now a **privileged intent**, so you must add it:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers], partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"] });
```

See [this page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents) in the guide.